# Convert a pandas dataframe to dictionary with one column as key and other column as multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, nlp

I want to convert this dataframe into a dictionary where for one single label as key, I store multiple tweets as value. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is variable name is "df" then below may help :

```
temp = df.groupby(['labels']).apply(lambda x: x['tweets'].tolist()).to_dict()
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get your expected result you can run e.g.:

```
result = df.groupby('labels')['tweets'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Details:

1. `df.groupby('labels')` - groups source rows.
2. `['tweets']` - takes only *tweets* column (from each group).
3. `apply(list)` - converts tweets from the current group into a list.
   You don't even need to use any explicit *lambda* function.
   So far (the result of *groupby* and *apply*) is a pandasonic *Series*.
4. `to_dict()` - converts this *Series* to a dictionary.

For your source data (shortened a bit) the result is:

```
{'EXP': ['if you missed', 'the emotional'],
 'QUE': ['the neverending'],
 'STM': ['katie couric', 'a yearold nigerian']}
```